# Will this RegEx match any Stack Exchange site?

Tags: regex

I have made this RegEx:

```
/http:\/\/(.+)?\.?(stackoverflow|superuser|serverfault|stackapps|stackexchange)\.com\/questions\/([0-9]+)\/?.*/i
```

It needs to match any Stack Exchange website's question. Is this the right RegEx? I have tested it and it works, but I've not tested it on all beta-sites and since I know I'm Satan in the RegEx world, I know there is something wrong (there is always something wrong with my RegExes xD).

Is this one good? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to do this with a regex? I think it would be better if you stored all the existing sites' urls somwhere and use this list instead. When you use a regex you will need to update it anyway once any of the beta sites goes live and chooses its domain...

Comment: I know a subdomain of `stackexchange.com` can be chosen, but can they also choose their own full domain?

Comment: Once they leave beta they are on track to becoming full-blown standalone sites with their own domain.

Comment: Mmm.. that's indeed a bit of a problem :/
Oh well, it's for an extra, undocumented feature for my website, if nothing happens (doesn't match); people won't know something should happen, and if something does happen (the RegEx does match); it's just extra awesomeness :)

Comment: You can create a simple webservice that will return a current list of all stackexchange sites.